# asp.net routing integration feature requires asp.net compatibility with webapi 0.6.0 and asp.net compatibility enabled

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, asp.net-web-api

using asp.net webapi v0.6.0 I get that error on launch. asp.net compatibility is enabled for the site. I've been trying to fix it for a couple of days now and frankly don't even know where to start.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Look at this topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12216791/wcf-asp-net-routing-integration-feature-requires-asp-net-compatibility

Answer (score 6):

Try adding the below to the system.servicemodel in web.config

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
```

Comment: I was already inculded in my project's web.congif     <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" /> but still i got this error