# WCF ASP.NET routing integration feature requires ASP.NET compatibility

Tags: wcf, rest, web-config

I am getting this issue when trying to access my web service from my server.

> ASP.NET routing integration feature requires ASP.NET compatibility.
>   Please see 'http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731336.aspx' on
>   how to do this.

I have added this line to my web.config just like many articles have suggested, yet I still get the same error.

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem when I had a website with no physical path configured. Configuring a physical path for the website fixed it.

```
# (PowerShell)
# Give it a physical path.    
mkdir C:\inetpub\wwwroot2
Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\Sites\$WebSiteName" `
    -Name physicalPath -value C:\inetpub\wwwroot2
```